# How to execute a custom command against a typed dataset

Tags: database, connection, command, strongly-typed-dataset

I want to execute a custom command against a typed dataset I created using the dataset designer. For this I need to get a reference to the underlying connection, right? How to go about this? In which autogenerated file can I find the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the ConnectionModifier property of the TableAdapter in the designer, is defaulted to Internal, so  you can use it in the same project/assembly, change it to Public and use it everywhere you need it. Or a better aproach will be create a partial class based in your TableAdapter name/namespace and encapsulate the logic within the same table adapter:

```
// if DataSet name is Sales and Table name is Order

namespace SalesTableAdapters // use full namespace here
{
    public partial class OrderTableAdapter
    {
        public void CustomCommand()
        {
            // here you can use the property this.Connection
            // and execute your command
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedTableAdapter ta = new myNameSpace.myDataSet.myDataSetTableAdapters.typedTableAdapter;

SqlClient.SqlCommand com = new SqlClient.SqlCommand("my query");
com.Connection = ta.Connection;
```